# How to print a message reporting an error with System.out.println that shows the invalid parameter but doesn't store it?

Tags: java

I need to print out the invalid parameter in the System.out.println message without storing it.

If the parameter is not between 1500 and 2000, I need to print a message saying "1400 is too early" or "2500 is too late".

I wrote this but unfortunately it only prints the default parameter for the integer (0):

```
    /**
     /* @param newModelYear is the model year of the car; invaild if the year is not in range between 1500 and 2000
     /*/
    public void setModelYear(int newModelYear){
        if ((modelYear <1500) && (modelYear >2000)) {
         modelYear=newModelYear;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(getModelYear + "sorry it is too early!");
        }
     }
```

Comment: There is no way an integer can be < 1500 and > 2000 at the same time. What is `getModelYear`?

Comment: ...Unless Jon Skeet wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up, it should be:

```
public void setModelYear(int newModelYear){
    if ( newModelYear < 1500 ) {
        System.out.println(newModelYear + ": sorry it is too early!");
    } else if ( newModelYear > 2000)) {
        System.out.println(newModelYear + ": sorry it is too late!");
    } else {
        modelYear=newModelYear;
    }
 }
```

Explanation: instead of

```
        System.out.println(getModelYear + "sorry it is too early!");
```

write

```
        System.out.println(newModelYear + "sorry it is too early!");
```

This uses the passed-in variable `newModelYear`.

And consider that you need `>= 1500` instead of `<1500` and `<= 2000` instead of `>2000`, as @JB Nizet said.

Thirdly, you might want to compare

```
    if ((newModelYear >= 1500) && (newModelYear <= 2000)) {
```

instead of

```
    if ((modelYear <1500) && (modelYear >2000)) {
```

Comment: it works! thanks a lot. it prints out the invalide parameter now without storing it! Thanks!

Comment: Please accept an answer if it helped you the most in finding your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have your signs wrong.
Change

```
if ((modelYear <1500) && (modelYear >2000)) {
 modelYear=newModelYear;
}
```

To

```
if ((modelYear > 1500) && (modelYear < 2000)) {
 modelYear=newModelYear;
}
```

Remember, > means "greater than". < means "less than"

These signs are called "Boolean operators". They take they left and right sides of the operator, return true or false. The < symbol takes the left number, and checks if the right number is bigger. If so, it returns true. If it isn't it returns false.

```
1 < 2
```

Returns true, because the number 1, on the left is less than the number 2, on the right.

if statements work using only true or false values. Everything you use inside it returns one of these values. Boolean operators take the values you use and turn them into boolean values that the if statement can use.

Comment: This is not inclusive. If you enter 1500 or 2000, the program will say the model year is invalid. Use `>=` and `<=` instead.

Comment: He said "in between", so I assumed he wanted a non-inclusive solution.

Comment: Ahh good point. I didn't notice that. I made the assumption that he would want it to be inclusive. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a try catch block (maybe more than one) to send the error you catch here to your parent code. See the below link for more details.

[Java: Proper way to throw and catch an exception to validate input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638954/java-proper-way-to-throw-and-catch-an-exception-to-validate-input)

Comment: There is no error here. In addition, user input should not be validated using try/catch blocks.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode, I agree that it shouldn't be validated by using try/catch blocks (and quite obviously there is not anything that throws an error in this code), but I do somewhat agree with this answer because some kind of error or error indicator should be returned to the caller. The code could throw some kind of exception to the caller. (And, in that case, the caller would need a try-catch block.) Or the code could just return a boolean (`false` if input is invalid, `true` if input is valid).

Comment: An exception isn't thrown, reducing the usefulness of a try/catch. Is would be better as a comment, as it does not directly answer the OPs question.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode, I'm not disagreeing with you there. I agree that it's better as a comment. All I am saying is that this user raises a good point. The caller (aka "parent code") should be somehow informed that the value was not valid.

Comment: That doesn't make it a valid answer... Sorry if I seem harsh, I was born and raised by the SO community

Answer (score 0):

The below code will resolve your problem

```
  public void setModelYear(int newModelYear){
       if(newModelYear < 1500){
          System.out.println("It is too early");
       }
        else if(newModelYear > 2500){
          System.out.println("It is too late");
       }
       else{
          modelYear=newModelYear;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to tackle this problem:

```
/**
 /* @param newModelYear is the model year of the car; invaild if the year is not in range between 1500 and 2000
 /*/
public boolean setModelYear(int newModelYear){
    if(newModelYear < 1500){
        // Too old
        System.out.printf("Error: %d is too old.%n", newModelYear);
        return false;
    }else if(newModelYear > 2000){
        // Too new
        System.out.printf("Error: %d is too new.%n", newModelYear);
        return false;
    }else{
        // Just right (In range)
        // Set the object's model year to the new value
        modelYear = newModelYear;
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Hopefully that will help you. There's not much to say, but if you have any questions about it, feel free to ask.

**Edit**: I added a return to the function. The code can be used without a return (`public void setModelYear(...)`), but I decided to change the function to return a boolean. If the `newModelYear` is valid and `modelYear` is changed, the function will return true to inform the calling function that the update was successful and the input provided was valid. Else, if the `newModelYear` is invalid, the code will still output an error to the console just like before, but it will now return false as well. If the returned value is false, this informs the caller that the input was not valid and `modelYear` was not changed.

Comment: @supergnagno, no problem. By the way, I updated the code to now return a boolean indicating if the `newModelYear` was valid or not. That can be used by your calling function to determine if the input was valid. Of course, that is entirely optional and the return value can be ignored (or omitted), but it's something I usually find useful for my own programs. Oh, and as the others have said, make sure you mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

You just have to check if modelYear is less than 1500 or greater than 2000 separately in order to print their respective errors, and then set the new value if the value is between 1500 and 2000.

```
public void setModelYear(int newModelYear){
    if (modelYear < 1500) {
        System.out.println(newModelYear + "sorry it is too early!");
    } else if (modelYear > 2000) {
        System.out.println(newModelYear + "sorry it is too late!");
    } else {
        modelYear = newModelYear;
    }
 }
```